# Troubles with positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning, 960.gs

I'm migrating from 960 grid to Twitter Bootstrap, which indeed is a headache. Right know I'm manipulating the ground structure (Base.html, using Django), but the output isn't at all what I want it to be. How can I accomplish what I want?

**Here's the html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <header id='header'>
        <!--Header content-->
    </header>
    <div id='main_container' class='row-fluid'>
        <div id="main" role="main" class="span12">
            <div id='main_content' class="span9">
                <!--Main content-->
            </div>
            <div id='side_bar' class="span3">
                <!--Sidebar container-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
 __________________________________
|                                  |
|             header               |
|__________________________________|
|                      |           |
|     main             |   side    |
|     content          |   bar     |
|                      |           |
|                      |           |
|                      |           |
|    <-------- main div ------->   |
|                      |           |
___________________________________
```

**Desired output:**

```
 __________________________________
|                                  |
|             header               |
|__________________________________|
|#####|               |      |#####|
|#####|   main        | side |#####|
| body|   content     | bar  | body|
| BG  |               |      | BG  |
|#####|               |      |#####|
|#####|               |      |#####|
|#####|   <--- main div ---> |#####|
|#####|               |      |#####|
___________________________________
```

**Note:**

I've tried to change `span12` in `<div id="main" role="main" class="span12">` to `span9`. Then it works, except that everything `main div` with it's content gets left aligned). This however can't be the right way of doing it, because that means that the `div`s inside the main `div` together will be `12` (`span9` + `span3`), even though the main `div` is `9`.

**Note 2:**
The "#####" is the body's background image, which means the main div should be centered and fill ~60% of the page horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

After sum of sibling divs with `.span` classes get result 12 (i.e. 12 = span9 + span3) you must set new div with `.row-fluid` class and then put other divs with `.span` classes inside of it. See [Twitter Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) (fluid nesting).

```
<div id='main_container' class='row-fluid'>
    <div id="main" role="main" class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div id='main_content' class="span9">
               <!--Main Container-->
           </div>
           <div id='side_bar' class="span3">
               <!--Sidebar Container-->
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: If you need to set offset to get desired result, try this

```
<div id='main_container' class='row-fluid'>
    <div id="main" role="main" class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span2">
               <!-- empty -->
           </div>
           <div id='main_content' class="span6">
               <!--Main Container-->
           </div>
           <div id='side_bar' class="span2">
               <!--Sidebar Container-->
           </div>
           <div class="span2">
               <!-- empty -->
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DSNnT/

Or you can use `offset` classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I realize now that I wasn't clear enough. The main div should not fill the whole page horizontally. The "#####" is meant to be the body's background image. With the solution you provided I get the desired structure, except that the main div is filling the whole page. Is there a way of compress the main div horizontally and still keep the structure?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to put the #main_container 'row-fluid' inside a 'container' like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id='main_container' class='row-fluid'>
    <div id="main" role="main" class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div id='main_content' class="span9">
               // main container
           </div>
           <div id='side_bar' class="span3">
               // sidebar container
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you 'desired output' shows a header-- is that the browser or do you want a 100% widget bar on the top? If so you could just put a nav on the top like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id='main_container' class='row-fluid'>
    <div id="main" role="main" class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div id='main_content' class="span9">
               // main container
           </div>
           <div id='side_bar' class="span3">
               // sidebar container
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have everything inside a container (i.e class='container') already, but that container also includes the header. Should I wrap the main div with it's content into another div with class='container'?

Comment: I tried your solution for the widget bar as well and it works except that it only reaches ~90% horizontally, which is strange. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes, just take it out if its' container.